# How to remove backslash escaping from a javascript var?

Tags: javascript, escaping

I have this var

```
var x = "<div class=\\\"abcdef\\\">";
```

Which is

```
<div class=\"abcdef\">
```

But I need

```
<div class="abcdef">
```

How can I "unescape" this var to remove all escaping characters?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can replace a backslash followed by a quote with just a quote via a regular expression and the `String#replace` function:

```js
var x = "<div class=\\\"abcdef\\\">";
x = x.replace(/\\"/g, '"');
document.body.appendChild(
  document.createTextNode("After: " + x)
);
```

Note that the regex just looks for one backslash; there are two in the literal because you have to escape backslashes in regular expression literals with a backslash (just like in a string literal).

The `g` at the end of the regex tells `replace` to work throughout the string ("global"); otherwise, it would replace only the first match.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `JSON.parse` to unescape slashes:

```
function unescapeSlashes(str) {
  // add another escaped slash if the string ends with an odd
  // number of escaped slashes which will crash JSON.parse
  let parsedStr = str.replace(/(^|[^\\])(\\\\)*\\$/, "$&\\");

  // escape unescaped double quotes to prevent error with
  // added double quotes in json string
  parsedStr = parsedStr.replace(/(^|[^\\])((\\\\)*")/g, "$1\\$2");

  try {
    parsedStr = JSON.parse(`"${parsedStr}"`);
  } catch(e) {
    return str;
  }
  return parsedStr ;
}
```

Comment: For me, with the slashes arising from JSON.stringify(), JSON.parse worked perfectly. Didn't need the str.replace(...) code

Comment: The `str.replace` is only needed if the string has an unescaped trailing slash, which will crash `JSON.parse`.

Comment: This will fail with { or } in the string

Comment: @ThomasWilliams seems to work fine with { or } for me https://jsfiddle.net/UziTech/npq5ba2L/

Comment: Try this:

`unescapeSlashes("Try this:\\n\\n\"{0}\" ID: {1}\\n\\nSome text")`

returns `"Try this:\n\n"{0}" ID: {1}\n\nSome text"`

Error inside says SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 15

Comment: Ah I think the issue is the `\"` your string is not double escaped so it returns the original string like it should.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to remove backslash escapes, but keep escaped backslashes, here's what you can do:

```js
"a\\b\\\\c\\\\\\\\\\d".replace(/(?:\\(.))/g, '$1');
```

Results in:
`ab\c\\d`.

Explanation of `replace(/(?:\\(.))/g, '$1')`:

`/(?:\\)` is a non-capturing group to capture the leading backslash

`/(.)` is a capturing group to capture what's following the backslash

`/g` global matching: Find all matches, not just the first.

`$1` is referencing the content of the first capturing group (what's following the backslash).

Comment: I would advise to remove the "global" flag though, as
`"a\\b\\\\c\\\\\\\\\\d".replace(/(?:\\(.))/, '$1');`
results in:
`ab\\c\\\\\d`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x = x.replace(/\\/g, "");
```

Comment: This will remove all backslashes, the question is how to remove backslash **escaping**.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = "<div class=\\\"abcdef\\\">";
alert(x.replace(/\\/gi, ''));
```

Comment: The `i` modifier  is not needed here.

Comment: Neither is the alert or the definition of x

Answer (score 0):

```
'<div class=\\\"abcdef\\\">'.replace(/\\\"/g, '"')
```

Other answers have you delete all backslashes, you only want to delete the ones befoew the quotes.

Answer (score -3):

You need to make there be one backslash instead of three.
Like this:

```
var x = "<div class=\"abcdef\">";
```

Answer (score -5):

Let me propose this variant:

```
function un(v) { eval('v = "'+v+'"'); return v; }
```

This function will not simply remove slashes. Text compiles as code, and in case correct input, you get right unescaping result for any escape sequence.

Comment: Using eval is a bad practice; unless you've carefully sanitized the data this could allow malicious code to execute.

Comment: but the way to unescape \056\045 like string