# javascript replace \ character

Tags: javascript, replace, special-characters

i've a pure javascript var containing the following value:

```
    var a = "\\{0\\}";
```

now what i need to do is replace the two \ before the first and latter bracket.

I've tried different solution, but no one seems to work

```
   var b = a.replace(pattern,'')
```

I can't find a good pattern. I don't know what to do or how to write a good pattern or a regexpr.

Anyone know the solutions? Thank to all

P.S. I need the solution in pure javascript.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640382/how-to-remove-backslash-escaping-from-a-javascript-var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = "\\{0\\}";
var pattern = /\\/g;
var b = a.replace(pattern,'');
```

Your problem is that you're dealing with escape characters, so you needed to use a regex.

---

edit: working example

http://jsfiddle.net/tylerpachal/HgBnw/

Comment: Thank you TylerAndFriend, but i've already tried your suggest and it doens't work.

I've found the solution, i don't know why but the pattern need \ 3 times

       var a = "\\{0\\}";
       var b = a.replace(/\\\/g, '');

       console.log(b) will print {0}

Comment: @user2548436 The above answer, with a pattern of `/\\/g`, worked for me. In Chrome console, the statement `"\\{0\\}".replace(/\\/g, '')` yields `"{0}"`. Using a pattern of `/\\\/g` gives a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var a = "\\{0\\}";
var b = a.replace('\\','').replace('\\','');
alert(b);
```