# How to unescape JavaScript string literal value?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) to parse [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) code (using an ES parser, such as Esprima, is not an option for technical environment limitations).

The subject code (the code being parsed is):

```
(function() {
    $('#3bf779cd').replaceWith("<div class=\'shows\'>\n<\/div>");

    window.fadeItems();
}).call(this);
```

The value I am interested in is the first parameter of `replaceWith`, which is a string literal. I am getting this variable using regex:

```
const subjectValue = subjectCode.match(/\.replaceWith\(((["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\3.)*?\2)/m)[1].slice(1, -1);

console.log(subjectValue);
```

The output of this is:

```
<div class=\'shows\'>\n<\/div>
```

How do I escape `subjectValue` in a way that the output would be:

```
<div class='shows'>
</div>
```

Simply using `unescape` has no effect.

If I am not mistaken, the question comes does to how to unescape this value:

```
console.log('"<div class=\\\'shows\\\'>\\\\n<\\\/div>"');
```

Comment: Looks like you need to use something like `replace`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640382/how-to-remove-backslash-escaping-from-a-javascript-var

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `eval` (yes you heard correctly):

```js
text = document.querySelector('script').textContent;

dqString = /"(\\.|[^"])*"/g

s = text.match(dqString)[0]

raw = eval(s);

alert(raw);
```

```html
<script>
(function() {
    $('#3bf779cd').replaceWith("<div class=\'shows\'>\n<\/div>");
    window.fadeItems();
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is an interesting (and effective) approach, but are there still considerations for using `eval` safely (see: [When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil). Also, your regex is loose enough to capture any `"` quoted string. If that is desired, you could get away with `/"[^"]+"/g`; but if you want to limit it to strings that contain a backslash, you should use a pattern similar to `/"[^"]*\\+[^"]*"/g`

Answer (score 0):

The most idiotic way would be.

```
"<div class=\\'shows\\'>\\\\n<\\/div>".replace(/\\n/g, '').replace(/\\/g, '');
// "<div class='shows'></div>"
```

Smarter way would be to first unescape \n's than check with regex if there are unescaped matches, and than escape those as well.